# Using \mintinline causes emergency stop

Tags: minted

Observe:

[image]
[image]

This implies the second use, which is at the end of line 169 is causing the error.
The use of `\mintinline{python}{merge_sort()}` is no difference to any other use. Does anyone have experience in this issue?

Comment: Hello and welcome to TeX.SX. It is quite hard for us to observe and understand the problem. Errors in LaTeX and TeX are... not dependable to say the least. To understand what really creates the stop we need a minimal working example: Short code that recreates the problem starting from `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`

Comment: If I had to guess, though, I'd go for the underscore causing the problem. try using `\_` or verbatim environment for such things